# React Unexpected token , expected "..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What am I doing wrong in this code, I don't know how else to write it I want to test the state `invalidForm` and render disabled or null depending.

state code UPDATE

```
if(valid) {
        return true;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        invalidForm: true
      })
    }
}


<button {this.state.invalidForm ? 'disabled' : null} type="submit">Submit</button>
```

The Error I am getting is

> ```
> Unexpected
>    token, expected "..."
> ```

Comment: it's not HTML, JSX uses an XML syntax, so you need to specify a full attribute="value" string: `<button disabled={this.state.invalidForm ? 'disabled' : false} [...]`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: That's not quite right: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true

Comment: CHECK YOUR FILE EXTENSION, SHOULD BE .tsx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[While you can define props without a value](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true), you cannot do that dynamically. Pass a value:

```
<button disabled={this.state.invalidForm}>Submit</button>
```

It shouldn't matter, but for clarity, if `this.state.invalidForm` is not a Boolean value, you can convert it to one:

```
<button disabled={Boolean(this.state.invalidForm)}>Submit</button>
```

Running example:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <button disabled={true}>Button 1</button>
    <button disabled={false}>Button 2</button>
  </div>,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

The parser expects `...` because the `{}` syntax inside an opening "tag" is reserved for "spreading" props from objects.

For example:

```
const props = {disabled: true};
return <button {...props}>Submit</button>
```

is the same as

```
return <button disabled={true}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I added some more code above when the form is invalid it sets a state with a key value of `invalidForm:true` so how do I remove the disabled when the invalid form is !true

Comment: @AndersKitson: It looks like you are not updating the state when the form is valid, so the component doesn't rerender to update the button. Instead of the `if ... else` statement you should be doing `this.setState({invalidForm: !valid});`.